# How to filter docker process based on image

Tags: docker, filtering

I have been trying to get the container id of docker instance using docker process command, but when i'm trying with filter by **name** it works **fine** for me.

```
sudo -S docker ps -q --filter="name=romantic_rosalind"
```

> Results container id :
>
> 3c7e865f1dfb

But when i filter using **image** i'm getting all the instance container ids :

```
sudo -S docker ps -q  --filter="image=docker-mariadb:1.0.1"
```

> Results Container ids :
>
> 5570dc09b581
>
> 3c7e865f1dfb

But i wish to get only container id of mariadb.

**How to get container id of docker process using filter as image ?**

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can use `awk` and `grep` to filter specified container id. 
For example:

```
docker ps | grep "docker-mariadb:1.0.1" | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

This will print id of your container.

Comment: something simpler: `docker ps | awk '/docker-mariadb:1.0.1/{print $1}'`

Comment: something more exact: `docker ps -a | awk '$2=="docker-mariadb:1.0.1" { print $1 }'`.

Comment: Example command >>>  docker container ls -af 'name=mysql' --format '{{.ID}}' <<<<

Answer (score 135):

Use "ancestor" instead of "image" that works great. Example:

```
sudo -S docker ps -q  --filter ancestor=docker-mariadb:1.0.1
```

The Docker team may have added it in the last versions:
http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

Comment: Ruben, I'm trying this approach but it returns the wrong container. Can you help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37255264/why-does-docker-filter-ancestor-imagename-find-the-wrong-container

Comment: This is more appropriate than using pipes

Answer (score 4):

```
docker ps -a | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | grep imagename | awk '{print $1 }'
```

This is perfect. if you need you can add a filter of running images of a particular stsatus alone,  like below

```
docker ps -a --filter=running | awk '{ print $1,$2 }' | grep rulsoftreg:5000/mypayroll/cisprocessing-printdocsnotifyconsumer:latest | awk '{print $1 }'
```

Various other filter options can be explored here

https://docs.docker.com/v1.11/engine/reference/commandline/ps/

Answer (score 3):

With a command `docker container ls` for listing containers( which is a replacement for `docker ps`) solution would be:

```
docker container ls | grep "docker-mariadb:1.0.1" | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

you may also use `*` sign(if needed) like this:

```
docker container ls | grep "docker-mariadb:*" | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_ls/

Comment: `grep x | awk '{y}'` is almost always better written `awk '/x/ {y}'` -- see [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html). But the proper solution is probably to decipher the `--filter` documentation and figure out how to get Docker to do this filtering for you.

Answer (score 2):

Example to command

```
docker container ls -af 'name=mysql' --format '{{.ID}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is accurate.

```
docker ps --all --format='{{json .}}' | jq -c '. | select( .Image=="docker-mariadb:1.0.1" )'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).