# Unable to change the working directory inside a docker container using python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, docker

I am able to get inside a docker container using below command

```
os.system('docker exec -ti $(docker ps -q -a --filter "name=XXXXX") /bin/bash')
```

and then i need to change to the following directory in the container.

```
/u01/oracle/weblogic/*****
```

when i use `os.chdir("/u01/oracle/weblogic/*****")`, i am getting `No such Directory error`.

I could see that `os.getcwd()` is still printing the previous directory where the python script is running instead of docker directory.

Could someone let me know what i am missing ?

Comment: When you run both commands after each other, you will change the working directory on your host machine where the script is on and not inside the container

Comment: So, how to get inside the container folder structure which is something like this `/u01/oracle/weblogic`

Comment: Use use the `subprocess` module instead of `os.system()` and pipe the command you want to use in. But in general: You should not do automated tasks from outside the docker container, that breaks the concept of docker.

Comment: Thanks a lot @KlausD. i will think in docker way !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the container name as exec parameter, instead of using a query to get the id?

You can use the -c parameter of bash to execute multiple commands. Like:

```
os.system('docker exec -ti XXXXX /bin/bash -c "cd /tmp;ls -alrt"')
```

Comment: This is amazing ! The -c flag did the magic for me. Thanks Robert :)

In my case, the docker container name and id are not consistent. Only consistent part is IMAGE. But i am unable to filter based on IMAGE. 

IMAGE will be something like this
`systemname.com:xxxx/xxx/xxxx:latest`

Comment: Got to see this thread which solved my other problem too :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29406871/how-to-filter-docker-process-based-on-image