# How to save docker container using on IMAGE name?

Tags: docker

To save a docker image currently running I search for the running image using `docker ps`

Use the IMAGE field from return of `docker ps` to find the container id to be saved :

```
docker save -o my-image.tar 'IMAGE ID'
```

Can this be combined in a single step ? In other words how to save a running docker container by IMAGE field returned by `docker ps` ?

Comment: See `docker ps --filter`  and `docker inspect`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29406871/1005215